# Can I display an image in the html src tag with only extension type and without the image name?

Tags: html

I want to display an image like : `<img src="*.png">`, where * can be any file name.

Reason for the question: I am sending an email to MS team with attaching an image: EX: `<img src="test.png">`. But MS teams added some extra characters to the attached image EX: **test_a1234.png**

So image is not getting displayed for my email.

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem.  No, there's really no way to effectively use wildcards here, the HTML isn't going to somehow figure out what you meant and go looking for the image.  Take a step back and address the root of the problem.  Where are you storing this image?  Where is your HTML?  Why can't you know the file name for the image?

Comment: Hi @David, As I am sending the image in the mail to Microsoft team channel, On runtime Microsoft team append some dynamic characters in the end of the image so src unable to read the image due to the new character.
When I am sending the automated email to outlook its working perfectly fine.